# Getting data from php localhost

Tags: android

I was trying to connect my android-login to php-localhost in order to use web server database(mysql) but im not able to do it due to error my code below.
Can you pls help me on this.. Thanks!
Android :

```
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/folder/jsonlogin.php");  
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   is = entity.getContent();
```

jsonlogin.php:

```
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='".$_REQUEST['username']."' and password='".$_REQUEST['password']."'")or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($q);
if($numrows > 0)
   {
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
   }
```

ERROR LOG:

[image]

Comment: a) change the HttpPost URL to "http://localhost/folder/jsonlogin.php" b) do you have said things running on your smartphone?

Comment: @oschlueter ive already done that now theres a new error ill see update

Comment: what is the your running device? is that emulator?

Comment: instead of posting the first line of a stack trace post the entire stack trace please

Comment: @oschlueter its on catch clause so thats the only error im getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("localhost/folder/jsonlogin.php");
```

This is the culprit. You're not specifying the protocol, this has to start with `http://`, so your `URL` should be like this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/folder/jsonlogin.php");
```

However, if you're calling this on a different machine where you're running the Android code, you'll have to specify the local IP address instead, something like: `http://192.168.X.YYY/folder/jsonlogin.php`.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? You should update your question by adding the Stack Trace of the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, you're getting this error because you're trying to perform a network operation (which is a `HTTP POST`) into the main UI thread. Doing so will make that your user cannot interact with your app meanwhile, resulting in a very poor user experience which will make your user not use your app anymore. That's why `Android` doesn't permit running network operations in your main thread. You'll need to do this within an `AsyncTask`, for instance.

Comment: This is yet another NetworkOnMainThread exception. Put the comms in an AsyncTask

Comment: Sure, just place it within an `AsyncTask`, concretely in its `doInBackground()` method. You'll see a very good example here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Just type 'NetworkOnMainThreadException' in that search box at the top of the StackOverflowpage and hit search. You will get 749 hits. Read some of them

Comment: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); add this into onCreat method

Comment: @anuruddhika This is really a bad practice. If it's set this way there's a reason, being this avoid at any price a Network operation on the main thread. If you posted this as an answer you'd probably got bombarded with downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are run using emulator you should use **10.0.2.2** instead of **localhost**

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/folder/jsonlogin.php");
```